# How to use torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss as autoencoder's reconstruction loss?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

I want to compute the reconstruction accuracy of my autoencoder using CrossEntropyLoss:

```
ae_criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
ae_loss = ae_criterion(X, Y)
```

where `X` is the autoencoder's reconstruction and `Y` is the target (since it is an autoencoder, `Y` is the same as the original input `X`).
Both `X` and `Y` have shape `[42, 32, 130] = [batch_size, timesteps, number_of_classes]`. When I run the code above I get the following error:

> ValueError: Expected target size (42, 130), got torch.Size([42, 32,
>   130])

After looking the docs, I'm still unsure on how should I call `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` in the appropriate way. It seems that I should change Y to be of shape `[42, 32, 1]`, with each element being a scalar in the interval `[0, 129]` (or `[1, 130]`), am I right?

Is there a way to avoid this? Since `X` and `Y` are between `0` and `1`, could I just use binary cross-entropy loss element-wise in an equivalent way?

Comment: `CrossEntropyLoss` is commonly used for classificaion problems. You should probably use an `MSELoss` or similar.

Comment: @iacolippo no, my dataset is composed of time series of discrete events, so I'm in fact doing classification.

Comment: Oh, my bad, misread the question. Is there a reason why you don't want to take the argmax over the last dimension? (Have idx of the class instead of one-hot vectors). Otherwise you can use `BCELoss` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Mainly it's just of computation efficiency, I wouldn't want to do the computation at every training iteration. But it seems the only way here, since my third dimension is the output of a softmax layer I don't think `BCELoss` is appropriate here.

Comment: if you look at how much time it takes to perform the argmax, I'm pretty sure it's negligible compared to all the rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

For `CrossEntropyLoss`, shape of the Y must be (42, 32), each element must be a Long scalar in the interval [0, 129].

You may want to use `BCELoss` or `BCEWithLogitsLoss` for your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that using `BCELoss` will be equivalent to `CrossEntropyLoss` in this case? My last dimension is the output of a softmax layer over 130 classes, not sure it's the same as using an element-wise `BCELoss`.